# how can i override the onclick event for events/items on a Calendar using JavaScript?

Tags: 2010, javascript, calendar, events

Right now when you click on an event on the calendar it selects it. I want to override that behavior. I can't seem to find what event to override. Any ideas?

I know I can iterate through each event/div but I figured there must be some function that gets called when a user clicks on an event. For example if they click on the title of the event it will call the `EditLink2` function which I can override.

But I can't find the function that is called when an event is just selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a small snippet from my blog which should get you where you need:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('calendarEventLinkIntercept');


// hook into the existing SharePoint calendar load function.
function calendarEventLinkIntercept()
{
if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a)
{
var OldCalendarNotify = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;
SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function ()
{
OldCalendarNotify();
bindEventClickHandler();
}
}
if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b)
{
var OldCalendarNotify = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function ()
{
OldCalendarNotify();
bindEventClickHandler();

}
}
// future service pack change may go here!
// if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.???)
}

function bindEventClickHandler() {
$('.ms-acal-mdiv a, .ms-acal-ddiv a, .ms-acal-sdiv a').click(function(){EditLink2(this,'WPQ2');return false;});
$('a.ms-cal-nav').attr("href", "javascript:bindEventClickHandler(); void(0);");
}
```

More at http://davidlozzi.com/2013/02/06/calendar-overlays-keeping-events-in-the-same-window/

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out. For now I just bound an `onclick` to the document and overrode the `EditLink2` function. That seems to be working but this seems like a better way.